# Second NVMe Not Visible in Arch (Razer Blade)

Tags: linux, ubuntu, arch-linux, nvme

I have a Razer Blade 15 Base 2020.

It came with a 512GB Samsung NVMe.  I got a second 2TB NVMe.  Windows recognized it just fine and initialized it with GPT then I split it in half and set the first half as NTFS and left the second half unallocated.

In arch (and also Ubuntu) however, the drive is not showing up at all.  It doesn't appear in `/dev`, with `lsblk`, or with `nvme list`.

Following info found online, I checked my bios, and it doesn't appear that any fastboot/raid/rapid storage mode is set.  And it seems to be set to AHCI mode.

So why can only Arch not see the drive?

lspci -nn:

```
03:00.0 Non-Volatile memory controller [0108]: Samsung Electronics Co Ltd NVMe SSD Controller SM981/PM981/PM983 [144d:a808]
04:00.0 Non-Volatile memory controller [0108]: ADATA Technology Co., Ltd. Device [1cc1:5370] (rev 01)
```

Results of `journalctl -k | grep nvme`

```
[    0.952062] nvme 0000:03:00.0: platform quirk: setting simple suspend
[    0.952230] nvme nvme0: pci function 0000:03:00.0
[    0.952272] nvme 0000:04:00.0: platform quirk: setting simple suspend
[    0.952326] nvme nvme1: pci function 0000:04:00.0
[    0.984554] nvme nvme1: Invalid MNAN value 0
[    0.984635] nvme nvme1: Removing after probe failure status: -22
[    0.986823] nvme nvme0: missing or invalid SUBNQN field.
[    0.986870] nvme nvme0: Shutdown timeout set to 8 seconds
[    1.000689] nvme nvme0: 12/0/0 default/read/poll queues
[    1.003047]  nvme0n1: p1 p2 p3 p4 p5 p6
[    1.459894] XFS (nvme0n1p6): Mounting V5 Filesystem
[    1.465545] XFS (nvme0n1p6): Ending clean mount
```

Comment: How does `lspci -k` look? And have you checked `dmesg` / `journalctl -k`?

Comment: @TomYan Added some output

Comment: https://github.com/torvalds/linux/commit/120bb3624d55d65145f7c1bf12a839fd323cde29 / https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/v5.18-rc3/drivers/nvme/host/multipath.c#L879 Apparently ADATA is not very good at following specification. But maybe it's not quite right to return -EINVAL because of that either. Rather the driver could e.g. assume that the ANA support is broken and ignore it. You can either write to the linux nvme mailing list about it, or ask ADATA to fix its firmware (probably way less likely to get any response though), or keep patching the kernel yourself.

Comment: @TomYan Updating firmware version of the ssd seemed to fix it.  I'll update relevant info in a bit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updating firmware using ADATA SSD Toolbox in windows fixed the issue.